# ComboBox MultiBinding with SelectionChanged Event

Tags: wpf

I want when a SelectionChanged event has fired on a ComboBox and 4 has been selected from the DropDown list a Popup should open. I can easily do this in code behind but I want to do it purely in XAML.

Here is a simple example.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow" Width="525" Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" Height="30" Width="200">
            <ComboBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Selector.SelectionChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ComboBox.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
        <Popup x:Name="MyPopup">
            <Grid Width="200" Height="200" Background="Yellow" />
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the Window Loaded event I have this simple code to load data into ItemsSource of the ComboBox:

VB.Net:

```
Private Sub MyComboBox_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyComboBox.Loaded
   MyComboBox.ItemsSource = New List(Of Integer)() From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
End Sub
```

C#:

```
private void MyComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyComboBox.ItemsSource = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

Basically I want to answer tow questions:

1). Has Selection taken place? YES

2). If so has 4 been selected? YES

If both conditions have been met then open a Popup

What I have done so far is to answer the first question. But how do I answer both questions in a MultiBinding scenario?

**I wish it was possible to do this way:**

```
<Setter Property="IsSelectionChanged" Value="true" />
```

Comment: If selection hasn't taken place then can 4 be selected? Just a datatrigger with selecteditem value=4 seems likely. Set the value of tag on the combo and bind isopen on the popup to that.

Comment: Yes the datatrigger seems likely but how can I combine it with the requirement that first I should check if there has been movement on (firing of) the SelectionCahnged event. The popup should only open if there has been a SelectionChanged action. Secondly this selection change should result into 4 being selected. These two events must occur before a Popup can be opened. I am not sure if I can place the second condition in the same StoryBoard (see main question).

Comment: How do you have a selection without selectionchanged firing?